# php mysql datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have two tables in MySQL, and each table has its own datetime field.
I want to copy the datetime of table A to overwrite the datetime of table B.
I use PHP.

```
$result = mysql_query("select * 
                         from A 
                        where id = $key");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
print $row[2]."\n"; // $row[2] is the datetime field
mysql_query("update B 
                set date_cal = $row[2]  
              where id = $key") // try to overwrite datetime in table B
```

$row[2] has the string representation of datetime field.

But the overwrite operation does not take effect.  How to do to overwrite datetime field of table B using php?

If I insist using $row[2] to assign the new datetime field rather running mysql_query again, how to do?

Comment: is it failing silently or throwing an error?  If so, what is the error?

Comment: Just a tip, you can do this directly in one sql query: `UPDATE b SET date_cal = (SELECT date_cal FROM a WHERE id = $key) WHERE id = $key`.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: It's called 'variable interpolation'.  `"WHERE ID = $key"` is valid, and PHP will replace `$key` with its value.

Comment: failing silently. No error throwing. The answers work. But if I need to use $row[2] to assign the datetime field, what should I do to make it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll need to wrap the date in quotes in your update query.

`mysql_query("update B set date_cal=$row[2] where id=$key")`
Should be
`mysql_query("update B set date_cal='$row[2]' where id=$key")`

On another note, I'd suggest that you *don't* access your fields by index when you're doing a `SELECT *` query.  If you add another field to your database, `$row[2]` could end up referring to something else.  If you instead call `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);`, you can refer to it by field name, eg
`mysql_query("update B set date_cal='{$row['date_field]}' where id=$key")`

Comment: Good point, depends on the data type.  If INT, doesn't need single quotes.

Comment: It works. But if I insist using $row[2] to assign the datetime field and do not use select query again, how can I do to make it correct?

Comment: If you don't plan on changing the database schema, then what you have is ok.  The problem is when you forget and change the database 6 months later, then wonder why your website is broken.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand that correctly, you can do the same from within your query:

```
update B 
   set date_cal = (select date_cal from A where id = {$key})
where id = $key
```

Comment: It works. But If I need to use $row[2] to assign the datetime field, what should I do to make it correct?